# Azure Elastic Scale/Database-per-tenant: how to implement data dependent routing

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, multi-tenant, azure-elastic-sharding

Based on the Microsoft Azure Elastic Scale sample apps online I have been able to create my Shard Map Manager (SMM) and elastic pool databases in Azure. My architecture is separate database per tenant. I am using Entity Framework in my web application. I am using a byte[] hash as my Shard Key based on an alphanumeric  customer name. The customer name is entered as part of customer login so I can determine the unique shard key at the time of login to be passed to the SMM.

My questions are:

1.) Since each tenant has its own database, do I still need to include the hashed customer name/shard Key in each row of the customer tables?

2.) I don't understand where the shard key information gets passed to the SMM during a call to the server. Is it within the context of the entity or does it need to be a part of the query itself? Any sample of this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You access the Shard Map Manager database when finding the connection string for a particular tenant.  Once you have the connection string, you connect to a tenant-specific database.  Inside the database you don't need to use the shard key at all.

The [Elastic Database Tools library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-database-client-library) has an implementation of [data dependent routing (DDR)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-scale-data-dependent-routing).  But you might find it overkill for when you have a simple [single tenant sharding pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-scale-introduction) implementation.  You can always just query the shard map database (or custom configuration store) at startup and load a `Dictonary<string,string>` to store the CustomerName -> ConnectionString lookup.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the clarification